# Как включить класс для проверки оставив его в области видимости функции?

Tags: php

Дело в том, что у меня в системе есть модули, у каждого модуля есть файл `main.php` с классом `Module`

Я делаю нечто подобное

```
private function CheckModule($moduleName) {
    if(is_file($incPath = INC_MODULE.$moduleName.'/main.php')){
        include $incPath;
        return class_exists('Module') ? 'valid' : 'class does not exist';
    } else {
        return 'wrong path';
    }
}
```

Этот метод проходится по все модулям. Проблема в том, что у классов одинаковые имена и они конфликтуют, я могу как-то не давать классу выбраться за пределы?

Comment: неймспейсы?....

Answer (score 1):

> Классы можно помещать в так называемые пространства имен (неймспейсы),
>   говоря иначе, полное имя класса может состоять из нескольких частей,
>   которые разделены бекслешем \ (не путай с прямым слешем /). Например:
>   полное имя Megasoft\Megacms\SomeClass, где Megasoft\Megamcs - это
>   пространство имен, а SomeClass - краткое имя класса.
>
> Неймспейсы, как и имена классов, принято писать с большой буквы.
>
> Пространства имен решают проблему слишком длинных имен классов.

[Источник](https://github.com/codedokode/pasta/blob/master/php/autoload.md)

Чтобы файлы не конфликтовали, необходимо использовать подход размещения классов в **[пространства имен](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php)**. Не вижу смысла описывать еще раз, что это такое, и как их использовать, таких вопросов здесь много, и на сайте php официальная документация все рассказывает в подробностях.

**Размещаете их в пространства имен и забываете про проблемы дублирования имен классов.**

Далее, ваш подход в корне неправильный, минимум в том, что у вас есть файл main.php в котором есть класс Module. Просто ли ориентироваться в коде, когда название класса и файла разное, да еще и не понятно где они находятся?

Для того, чтобы решить вашу проблему и предотвратить будущие проблемы архитектуры, нужно начать разработку с использованием стандартов **PSR**. Желательно прочитать все и запомнить их. Например, [Стандарт PSR-4](http://svyatoslav.biz/misc/psr_translation/#_PSR-4) "улучшенной автозагрузки", он описывает спецификацию для автозагрузки классов на основе путей файлов.